How do you transform SAML 2 claims to readable values?
I am using the ITFoxTec SAML 2.0 library in a .Net Core 2 web app.
When my app authenticates with an IdP, I am trying to get the email address back.
So I wrote out the contents of: saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity
I see the email in there, but it's a odd long string that looks like this:
urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6: James.Iha@sp.edu
How do I get the just the values like last name, email, etc... without all the other stuff that comes along with it?
Thanks!

You iterate over the claims for the claimsidentity; that gives you the properties for each of the claims in separate fields.
To get just the email:
var email = saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6")?.Value;

to enumerate all claims and their values:
foreach (var claim in saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.Claims)
{
    Console.WriteLine(claim.Type);
    Console.WriteLine(claim.Value);
}

